# JavaScript: How to make the directory in a string work

Tags: javascript

The following is one piece of javaScript code.

```
{$("#message").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' />");}
```

"images/" was not recognized by the computer.

Comment: Why wasn't it recognized? Was it going to the wrong directory on the server?

Comment: What is the full URL of the page that runs this code, and the full URL of `ajax-loader.gif`?

Comment: Remember that relative URLs will be interpreted by the browser starting from the directory of the page the HTML is loaded into. So if the page is `/dir1/dir2/page.html`, it will look for `/dir1/dir2/images/ajax-loader.gif`

Comment: It was figured out that is the permission issue. The image folder does not have enough permission.